# How to save cat() function output as a value in R?

Tags: r, list, null, cat

When I run the following code in RStudio the output is returned in the console, but it doesn't save as a value in the global environment - instead, it returns as a NULL value. I've noticed this occurs every time I use the `cat()` function. Why is this the case and how can I fix this?

```r
test <- cat(paste0(c("hello", "\n", "goodbye", 
                     capture.output(sessionInfo())
)))
```

[image: console output]
[image: global env]

Comment: From [`?cat`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html): *"Value: None (invisible 'NULL')"*. That function works entirely in side-effect.

Comment: Why not `test <- c("hello", "goodbye", capture.output(sessionInfo()))`?

Comment: `cat` returns `NULL`. To capture its output, well, `capture.output(cat(etc))`. It seems confusing because in the question you have `capture.output` *inside* `cat`. This inner function is about `sessionInfo`, the outer one is about `cat`.

Comment: You can move the assignment inside `cat()`: `cat(test <- paste0(c("hello", "\n", "goodbye", 
                     capture.output(sessionInfo())
)))`

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? You should think of `cat` only as an output stream (because it is one), not as a formatting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising the answers in the comments the two solutions are:

1. Do not use `cat()` at all since it is a function to create a console output and it is not necessary to store the data.

```r
test <- paste0(c("hello", "\n", "goodbye", 
               sessionInfo()[1:5]))
test # or cat(test)
#> [1] "hello"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#> [2] "\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#> [3] "goodbye"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#> [4] "list(platform = \"x86_64-w64-mingw32\", arch = \"x86_64\", os = \"mingw32\", system = \"x86_64, mingw32\", status = \"\", major = \"4\", minor = \"0.3\", year = \"2020\", month = \"10\", day = \"10\", `svn rev` = \"79318\", language = \"R\", version.string = \"R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)\", nickname = \"Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out\")"
#> [5] "x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#> [6] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#> [7] "Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#> [8] "c(\"Mersenne-Twister\", \"Inversion\", \"Rejection\")"
```

1. Capture the output of the console not only around session info but around the whole thing.

```r
test <- capture.output(cat(
  paste0(c("hello", "\n", "goodbye", sessionInfo()[1:5]))
))
test
#> [1] "hello "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#> [2] " goodbye list(platform = \"x86_64-w64-mingw32\", arch = \"x86_64\", os = \"mingw32\", system = \"x86_64, mingw32\", status = \"\", major = \"4\", minor = \"0.3\", year = \"2020\", month = \"10\", day = \"10\", `svn rev` = \"79318\", language = \"R\", version.string = \"R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)\", nickname = \"Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out\") x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252 Windows 10 x64 (build 19041) c(\"Mersenne-Twister\", \"Inversion\", \"Rejection\")"
```

NOTE: for demonstration purposes I limited the session info to the first 5 elements.

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>